# Proof by induction of a given inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

I am trying to solve the underneath problem. I managed to get the initial proof but to generalize on $n+1$ I failed.

> Show that for any natural $n\geq 2 $   and any real  $a_i$  we have :
>   $$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2 \leq 2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2.$$

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the inductive step you may apply the $n$-case inequality to 
$$a_1,a_2,\dots, a_{n-1},(a_n+a_{n+1}).$$
Hence
$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i)^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i+(a_n+a_{n+1}))^2 \leq 2^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^2+(a_n+a_{n+1})^2\right).$$
So it remains to show that
$$2^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^2+(a_n+a_{n+1})^2\right)\leq
2^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^2$$
that is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^2+(a_n+a_{n+1})^2\leq
2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^2+2a_n^2+2a_{n+1}^2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Enough clear, I guess I have to work more on the abstraction model to get full scope of the problem. Thanks a lot for your precious  Help. ( Sorry for the Vote, I need 15 reputations to vote, and I just posted my first question here )

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 solutions of the above inequality:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2 \leq 2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2.$$
Let me join the fun:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2\ =
    \ \sum_{i=1}^n\,(a_i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n a_j)\ \le
    \ \frac 12\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n\,(n\!\cdot\! a_i^2+\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2)
    \ =\ n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 $$
i.e.
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2\ \le\ n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 $$

which is clearly much better than our original OP's goal --
**indeed**, $\ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\, n\le 2^{n-1}.$

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality $(a+b)^{2} \leq 2(a^{2}+b^{2})$.  If $s_n= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_i$ then $(s_n+a_{n+1})^{2} \leq 2(s_n^{2}+a_{n+1}^{2}) \leq 2(2^{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_i^{2}+a_{n+1})^{2}$. Can you take over from here?

Comment: yes, I got it. it's clear now.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without induction we have $$ 2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)^2= $$ $$= 2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}2a_ia_j=$$ $$= (2^{n-1}-n)\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2+(n-1)\sum_{i-1}^na_i^2-\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}2a_ia_j=$$ $$=(2^{n-1}-n)\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\,+\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(a_i-a_j)^2\ge 0$$ because $2^{n-1}- n\ge 0.$